# ¿Existe un modismo en español equivalente a "to hit the ground running"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-modismo

El modismo `to hit the ground running` tiene el significado de

> to immediately work hard and successfully at a new activity <sub>Cambridge dictionary</sub>
>
> to begin a venture with great energy, involvement, and competence.
>
> to make immediate and rapid progress  <sub>Collins dictionary</sub> 
> ​

es decir "(poder) empezar a trabajar en algo inmediatamente, con ganas, energía y demostrando competencia en la labor a realizar", "progresar de manera rápida e inmediata".

Es muy frecuente encontrar este modismo en descripciones de trabajo, queriendo expresar que la empresa espera poder contratar a alguien y que esa persona pueda empezar a ser productiva desde el primer día, sin mucha supervisión.

Supongo que en español podríamos decir "empezar con ganas" o "arrancar con fuerza", pero me pregunto si hay un modismo mejor que recoja el significado de `to hit the ground running`.

Comment: Para esto, yo conozco la frase, _ponerse las pilas_, que es como darle energía al organismo, al igual que ocurre con los aparatos electrónicos.

Comment: @ArtEze pues tiene sentido. La letra de _All Star_, dle grupo Smash Mouth, dice "fed to the rules and I hit the ground running". Desde luego queda claro si se traduce como "empecé a seguir las normas y me puse las pilas".

Comment: En Chile es muy frecuente empezar "con las pilas puestas", como aporta ArtEze. También tenemos el dicho _partida de caballo inglés_, que significa "empezar con energía y mostrar pronto buenos resultados, _pero decayendo al poco tiempo_". Lamentablemente esa decadencia hace que el modismo no sirva para lo que pides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En su entrada [*hit the ground running*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=hit%20the%20ground%20running), WordReference tiene una entrada para este modismo y sugiere unas cuantas, dividiéndolas en dos tipos.

Para cuando empiezas con mucho entusiasmo:

- **acometer con ilusión**
- **arrancar a toda marcha**

Para cuando empiezas siendo plenamente competente en la materia:

- **empezar con el pie derecho**

---

No quiero dejar de destacar que en la sección de discusiones relacionadas encuentro un par de expresiones que podrían encajar:

- Coger el toro por los cachos  <sub>([referencia](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hit-the-ground-running.424813/#post-2469127))</sub>
- Llegando el payaso y soltando la risa  <sub>([referencia](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/hit-the-ground-running.158927/#post-11187350))</sub>

La primera en España la diríamos *coger el toro por los cuernos* y es algo más genérica, pues se usa para designar el acto de acometer una empresa difícil, sin ambages ni procrastinaciones.

La segunda [parece](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/10749-viendo-el-payaso-soltando-la-risa) que tiene un significado distinto y en Costa Rica se refiere a cerrar tratos. La dejo aquí por si alguien puede dar más datos al respecto.